# Confused by the notation in Steele's Stochastic Calculus

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Recently started Steele's Stochastic Calculus text and as I was going through the first chapter.

[image: excerpt]

While making a case for why $\tau$ is finite he introduces a super-script of $d$ on the variables without any prior mentions of the same.

Anybody who has studied the text before, could you perhaps afford some clarity on what this denotes and means in this context.

Would be extremely grateful for any responses.

Comment: In the first sentence he writes "we can even decide from equation (1.3) that $\tau$ has moments of all orders". Based on this it seems to me that $\tau^d$ is simply  $\tau$ to the power $d$ with $d \in \mathbb{N}$. He wants to show that $E[\tau^d] <\infty$, for all $d\in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $\tau$ has finite moments of all orders.

Comment: Also, if you are initiating your study in Stochastic Calculus, consider having a look at the book: "Introduction to Stochastic Integration", by Hui-Hsiung Kuo. It's a great introductory book.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar, same question that I asked Jose, what would proving the same achieve? Isn't proving that stronger than what he has set out to prove, i.e $E(\tau)$ is finite.

Comment: Showing that all moments exist would show in particular that the first moment, i.e. $E[\tau]$, exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superscript $d$ on $\tau$ means the standard thing; i.e. $\tau^d$ is $\tau$ to the power of $d$.

Comment: What would proving the above inequality for all $\tau^d$ achieve though?

Comment: @VivaanGupta it shows all the moments exist